# Laravel 8 asset helpers not working in my new project

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-8

so I created a new laravel project and use npm run dev to generate my css file inside public folder.
like my last project i tried to load my CSS like this

```
     <link href="{{ URL::asset('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

but that doesn't work. my folder structure is like this

```
public
  css
   app.css
```

I checked a lot of posts but non of them worked. the only way to load the file is like this

```
<link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

or

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

my question is why asset helper don't work ?

i tried changing the url, changing env 'ASSET_URL', etc

I know this is a really elementary issue, but this question are making me crazy,
btw my last project laravel version was 7 but this one version is 8

Comment: Why did you add an assets folder in `'/assets/css/app.css'`?

Comment: @ brombeer ye i forgot to delete that from code sry gono update this thx for mentioning that.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
"npm run prod" if laravel-mix v5
"npx --production" if laravel-mix v6

Comment: @BossCOTIGA as i said mix working right now, i am looking for a reason why asset not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper path in laravel `asset()` helper function.
`asset()` helper function access from `app/public` directory.

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: yes that was a typing problem sorry, the problem still exist

Comment: Try with 2nd solution, like `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
`

Comment: check it by `dd(asset('css/app.css'))` in your view and see what is the result ?

Comment: @AlAminSarker it return "http://localhost/css/app.css"

Comment: @AlAminSarker I got an idea when you said to check the url, and i compare that with mix and by changing the .env i fixed the problem, so Thank you, your answer gave me an idea to find the problem

Comment: Great one task.